# Event sourcing: avoid projects duplicated events while replaying events and listen new incoming events

Tags: event-sourcing

In the scenario where it needs to build a new view, we could replay all the events from the *EventStore*. As a result we'll have the new view projected.

So, the idea is deploy a new projection that projects all old events (by replaying) and also listen new incoming events and project them.

I think that races conditions can occur while reading olds events and listen new incoming events. As a result we could project the same event more than once and then corrupt the new view.

So, what is good approach to draw a line between events to be replayed and new incoming events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[EventStore](https://geteventstore.com/) supports this scenario via [Catch-up Subscriptions](https://geteventstore.com/blog/20130306/getting-started-part-3-subscriptions/)

You would specify the very start of the stream as the starting point for the subscriber, it would then process all events up until "now" and then start listening to events that come in.

```
Connection.SubscribeToStreamFrom(
    StreamName, 
    checkpoint, 
    resolveLinkTos,
    OnEventReceived,
    OnLiveProcessingStarted, 
    OnSubscriptionDropped);
```

You even get an event for when you start processing live. :)

More general advice for this sort of thing:

1. Make the process idempotent, so it doesn't matter if you receive the same event twice
2. De-duplicate on the receiving end - you'd need to keep a record of which events had already been processed

Answer (score 1):

From a Greg Young talk, I can summarize that *EventStore* works similar to an Atom feed. So projections (aka subscribers) poll events since an *id* tracking which subscriber maintain.

Then EventStore knows nothing about if a new projection needs replay all events or not. EventStore, in Greg Young words, receives

> Give me 'n events' after 'x'

Comment: No, you are not describing the GES correctly. You have listened to his talk where he is describing some edge use cases when their customers use GES for integration and other exotic reasons. Whilst being completely valid use cases, this is not related to event sourcing.

Comment: Sorry, I dont see how this relates to the original question. You're correct in that the position a subscriber is at in a stream is the responsibility of the subscriber, but your original question was about bringing up a new subscriber and avoiding processing duplicate events which I think my answer addresses. In this example, X is start of stream (-1?). Also agree with alexey that this isnt to do with eventsourcing

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev, (@)tomliversidge Please check the following talk from 41:30 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBzS9JoMJW0 Maybe I don't understand well, however I think he explains it very well. Otherwise please clarify it with a new answer. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @martinezdelariva You have the correct answer above. We also use catch-up subscriptions, which first give you all events that are already stored and then starts giving you real-time events. The same is valid for internal GES projections, there is an option for that. It will *not* process new events, until all historical events are processed. There will be no "race condition" there.

Comment: I just watched the video from the point you said and the one-liner Greg describes is the example in my answer from EventStore